# Single table inheritance and relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, single-table-inheritance

I'm trying to find a solution for a this problem:

We have a table (`code_list`) in the database which contains all `enum` -like data.

Let us say we have an `Affiliate` that can have an `AffiliateType` and a `LanguageCode`.

We put all this in the `code_list` table where `id_code_list` field tells us if we are talking about `AffiliateType` or `Languagecode` and we can have a `String` or `Integer` identifier that tells us about which `AffiliateType` we are talking.

Example of the data in table:

```
    | id_code_list | val_num | val_string | label  |
    | :----------: |:------: |:---------: | :-----:|
    | TYP_AFF      | 3       | 3          | Other  |
    | TYP_AFF      | 1       | 1          | Divers |
    | COD_LAN      | 1       | 1          | French |
```

I tried to map this that way:
**Code List Parent**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CODE_LIST")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "ID_CODE_LIST")
public abstract class CodeListString {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "VAL_STRING")
    protected String value;

    @Embedded
    protected Label label;
...
```

**Affiliate Type:**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TYP_AFF")
public class AffiliateType extends CodeListString{

    public static final AffiliateType SOCIAL_SECRETARIAT = new AffiliateType("1");
    public static final AffiliateType VARIOUS_SERVICES = new AffiliateType("2");
    public static final AffiliateType OTHERS = new AffiliateType("3");
    public static final AffiliateType SOPA = new AffiliateType("9");

    public AffiliateType() {}

    private AffiliateType(String value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

And my `Affiliate` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AFF")
public class Affiliate {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TYP_AFF")
    private AffiliateType type;
```

But I'm getting this error:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK7re97tvvbbo2km961gy9b5jw6:aff [typ_aff])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (code_list [val_string,id_code_list])

So, is there a way to make this work or do you have other solution for this problem ?

**PS:** I'm using Hibernate and the solution like

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = AffiliateType.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "TYP_AFF")
@Where(clause = "ID_CODE_LIST='TYP_AFF'")
private AffiliateType type;
```

Doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I've removed a dependency to a custom library and this worked.

I could not reproduce this error on a clean project.

Anyway this solution is really slow !